# Error with tableofcontents while using ngerman in Markdown

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, compilation-error, german, rmarkdown

I am new here and I need some help with my Markwodn document. I encoutered a nasty problem: When I try to knit my PDF, it gives me this error:

```
tlmgr.pl: Remote database (revision 69711 of the texlive-scripts package)
seems to be older than the local installation (rev 69718 of
texlive-scripts); please use a different mirror and/or wait a day or two.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \babel@toc
               {nil}{}\relax
```

This is what my YAML-Header looks like:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document
   
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{ngerman}
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \onehalfspacing
  
csl: chicago-author-date.csl
bibliography: Heuschrecken.bib
---
```

And this are the libraries I am using:

```
library(xlsx)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lsr)
library(ggpmisc)
library(readxl)
library(rbbt)
library(pandoc)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tinytex)
```

The problem occurs when i try to insert my toc

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

I isolated the error and it only occurs when I am using the \tableofcontents command. Surprisingly it works just fine when I am using \listoffigures or \listoftables.
I am happy for any suggestion on how to fix this error.

My system is a Win 10, 64x - if this could be relevant.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does it work without ngerman?

Comment: do not use `\usepackage{ngerman}`, use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: @Ulrike tried it and it produced another error: 

`! Package babel Error: Unknown option 'ngerman'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file ngerman.ldf
(babel)                was not found.
(babel)                There is a locale ini file for this language.
(babel)                If it’s the main language, try adding provide=*'
(babel)                to the babel package options.`

I tried this with provide and it knits my file, but it will not translate anything in the document.

Comment: Install whatever package is needed for  German support. Texlive-lang-german or something like that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it should be installed. I used ngerman in an other document and it works fine there...

Comment: You used above the package ngerman, that is something different to the file babel is looking for and if babel says it is missing I trust the babel error more than your claim. Find out how you install more packages in your texsystem and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It had nothing to do with any installation. I copied everything I had in a different RMarkdown document and it worked. I don't know why, but now it is fine.